# Unable to compare strings in c++ without using variables

Tags: c++, string

I do not get the right answer when I compare the strings in c++ without assigning them to variables.

```
    string a = "286";
    string b = "256";

if("286" > "256") cout << "yay";
else cout << "nope";    

cout <<endl;

if(a > b) cout << "yay";
else cout << "nope";
```

Output :

nope
yay

Is it not possible to compare strings without using variables? Why?

Comment: String literals are arrays of characters (`const char [N]`), not strings.

Comment: `if("286" > "256")` does compare two `const char*` pointers, not `std::string`s. You could change your condition to be explicit though: `if(std::string("286") > std::string("256")) cout << "yay";`

Comment: Modern C++ has the ability to do `"286"s` (note the `s` suffix) which is a string literal.

Comment: Seems like a well asked question to me, why's it being downvoted?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it not possible to compare strings without using variables?

It is obviously possible, but you need to understand what you are comparing.

When you write this:

```
"abc" < "cbe"
```

you compare two `const char *` so basically you check which address is lower. To compare them as strings you need to convert at least one of them:

```
std::string( "abc" ) < "cbe"
```

or more verbose:

```
static_cast<std::string>( "abc" ) < "cbe"
```

or use string literals:

```
using namespace std::string_literals;

"abc"s < "cbe"s
```

then you will compare 2 `std::string` objects (like you do when you use named variables).

Answer (score 2):

Slava's answer covers the most proper way to do so in C++, and it's certainly the most readable one - you should prefer it in normal situations.

The other solution (without involving `std::string` and in style typical to C programming) would be to use [`std::strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp):

```
#include <cstring>

if(std::strcmp("286", "256") == 0) 
    cout << "yay";
else 
    cout << "nope";
```

Note that this is much more unsafe code (behaviou is unspecified if any of the arguments to `std::strcmp` is not a pointer to null-terminated char array) and arguably less readable.